# Avoid FOR loop to append several strings to list

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, append, list-comprehension

I need to update a DataFrame column with some strings at selected rows, for which I have the index. 
So far, I managed to achieve what I need with list comprehension:

```
[data.particleIDs.values[idx[i]].append(particlenames[i]) for i in range(len(idx))]
```

where `data.particleIDs` is the DataFrame column that needs to be updated, `particlenames` a list containing the strings and `idx` an array containing, for each string, the DataFrame row it needs to be written on. Several strings correspond to the same row, and I need to write them all in the DataFrame column.

Let's say I have a DataFrame and the list of strings that I use to update it:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'particleIDs': [[] for i in range(20)]}
particlenames = ['c15001'+str(i) for i in range(10))]
```

I have 10 strings and I need to use them to update the rows `[7 8 15 8 11 0 15 1 12 8]` in my DataFrame, i.e. I need to add each string to the corresponding row.

The FOR loop is terribly slow, as the actual `particlenames` list is long and I need to repeat this process several times.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Thank you!

Comment: Some samle input and output data would help us to understand your issue better, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Done! Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: So what is the expected result? You are updating the same row multiple times (e.g. row `8` is updated three times with values 'c150011', 'c150013' and 'c150019').

Comment: Yes, I need that!
I also tried with .loc, but I can't get that result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating another dataframe for the strings and the corresponding 
indices:

```
df_strings = pd.DataFrame({'strings':particlenames,'rows':[7, 8, 15, 8, 11, 0, 15, 1, 12, 8]})
```

and then by using the `groupby` method on rows to append the strings with `apply(list)`:

```
df_strings=df_strings.groupby('rows')['strings'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Finally, I `join` this new DataFrame with the one (`data`) that needs to be updated with the strings:

```
data=data.join(df_strings.set_index('rows'))

data=

    particleIDs     strings
0   []  [c150015]
1   []  [c150017]
2   []  NaN
3   []  NaN
4   []  NaN
5   []  NaN
6   []  NaN
7   []  [c150010]
8   []  [c150011, c150013, c150019]
9   []  NaN
10  []  NaN
11  []  [c150014]
12  []  [c150018]
13  []  NaN
14  []  NaN
15  []  [c150012, c150016]
16  []  NaN
17  []  NaN
18  []  NaN
19  []  NaN
```

So I can avoid adding the `particleIDs` when creating the `data` DataFrame (which, in my real case, has other columns), as the joined column contains the info I need.